# How to install or configure external library pyreadr in Portable Python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

How to install or configure external library pyreadr in Portable Python successfully. I am on a Windows 10 64-bit machine. How would I be able to use the external libraries from before.

I was able to successfully install the library for my installed Python version, however I was not able to configure the library with the portable python.

I have tried installing the library from the portable python location but it always installs the library to installed python and not portable python.

I also tried to copy all the library files and paste in the python portable library but I still was not able to run the pyreadr from python portable.

I am looking for a way to install library in portable python without changing the path in environment variable.

Please let me know if you have any solution or alternative for this so I can configure pyreadr in my python portable.

Thanks for your time.